# How to create an InstantRails clone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows

I'd like to create a new InstantRails-type app for Rails developers who use Windows. It would be free & open-source of course.

Reasons:

- Use nginx over Apache, especially
  since the nginx guys are now
  releasing original Windows versions.
- Use the newest version of Rails.

I haven't developed a Windows app before. Could anyone please provide some general steps that I might look into to get something like this going?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the most part InstantRails is just an encapsulation of all the software necessary to get things rolling -- Ruby, Rails, MySQL, Apache, and so on.  There's no reason you can't package things up the same way; just look at how they do it.  The only app you'd need to write is your equivalent of the manager, and if you're going to use a GPL-compatibile license, you could simply modify the [InstantRails-Mgr](http://instantrails.rubyforge.org/svn/trunk/InstantRails-win/InstantRails-Mgr/).